# Cannot delete directory on External drive

Tags: ntfs, external-hdd, delete

I was using Rsync to copy files from my laptop to external HDD (probably NTFS formatted since I can use it under another Windows machine). Somewhere in the middle the connection got interrupted and the drive was mounted again by itself.

Not knowing about Version control, I tried to delete the whole newly copied directory - only problem I cannot.

Someone on the internet posted a solution saying `chattr -i [filename]` and it gives the output `input output error, cannot stat [filename]` with the name of a video file coming up that should have been deleted.

How may I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

1- you need to find what file system it is.

2- check that the file system is repaired. Do it in some proprietary system, or try with `fsck` (but Linux cannot repair all filesystems)

3- then I think you can either delete the directory, or the directory is gone (because it was already partially removed).

I assume your file-system it is in a inconsistent state.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you used `rsync`, you're file ownership may have changed when copying to the new destination. Check your file on your external HDD for owner and group matching.

Also, provide more information to better diagnose your problem: i.e.) OS, commands, outputs, etc..

**Note**: if you want to use version control, try [`git`](https://git-scm.com) for true version control.